# Pyside Translucent Window Feature Not Working - 3ds Max, Maya, Desktop

Tags: python, user-interface, background, pyside, translucency

This is a pretty superficial post but I figured I'd add it anyway and see what comes of it.

I have been wanting to create more unique, visually pleasing interfaces for a while now. One of the main things I would love to add to a small window is a translucent/transparent effect on just the background of the Window (not buttons and text and everything else on top). I searched for this and came up with a few suggestions but none of them worked. They were the following:

**Setting the widget's QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground attribute to true. This just turns the background black.**

```
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
```

**Setting the window opacity to a given value between 0.0 and 1.0. This set the opacity for EVERYTHING in the window. Buttons, fields, text, and all. Not what I hoped for.**

```
self.setWindowOpacity(0.75)
```

And there were other suggestions that I didn't understand nor did I know how to implement. I would love to be able to use a png file with transparency for the widget background and have it show through. Not sure if this is possible or not or if 3ds Max or Maya (or other Applications with PySide compatibility) would even allow for it but I figured I'd ask anyway. Thanks.

Comment: If you are on linux, that is dependent on your linux theme settings.

Comment: Its on Windows. I had someone else tell me you have to use PySide2 but I tried "pip install"-ing but it didn't work.